# Error: yq@3 has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream! How to install a disabled brew Formulae?

Tags: homebrew, deprecated, yq

I'm trying to install yq@3 on my Mac running brew install yq@3 and I get the error:

```
Error: yq@3 has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!
```

I see that it's there on their website at https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/yq@3#default but it doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

I still need to install it since our projects at work are using this specific version.

The only way that I'm thinking about is downloading the source code, building it myself, and adding it to the path but I'm thinking that there might be a simpler solution.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you install disabled Homebrew packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73586208/can-you-install-disabled-homebrew-packages)

Answer (score 6):

From [yq github](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq#plain-binary), you can install a binary by running:

```
wget https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/3.4.1/yq_darwin_amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/yq &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/yq
```

`3.4.1` is the latest `3` version, `darwin_amd64` is the Mac package (don't worry about having an Intel machine and installing the package that says AMD, the name comes from something about AMD invented the 64-bit instruction set).